# CSS block level link color overrides to default in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have block level links, which contain other block level elements with a different color.

The problem I have is that once you visited that link Google Chrome shows the a:visited color, and not the specific colors of his children.

I've made a jsfiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/yvesvanbroekhoven/UTwgU

You can see the difference in Firefox & Google Chrome. Click on the link and then it the colors of the title & text should be red/green, but in Chrome they become purple.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently it's a problem with a specific version of Chrome (16.0.912.0 dev). Just tested it in a lower version an works like expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid HTML. You can't havr a block level element within an inline one. Put links inside the other tags:

```
<h1>
    <a href="http://google.com" target="blank">Title</a>
</h1>
<p>
    <a href="http://google.com" target="blank">Intro text</a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
h1 a  {
  color: red;
}

p a {
  color: green;
}
```

To style a visited link, use:

```
p a:visited{
    color: green;
}
h1 a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UTwgU/3/).

Comment: In HTML 5 you can do that: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/. Maybe indeed I had to put display: block; in the <a> in my example.

Comment: You didn't mention it was html5. And yes, add display: block; to your code :)

Answer (score 0):

It is red/green in my chrome (v 14.0.835.202)!
Anyway you can set the colors as you want:

```
a:visited p{
    color: green;
}
a:visited h1{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to work as expected in Chrome 17.

If `a` link styles aren’t inheriting to child block-level elements, try using `inherit`, eg:

```
<header>
<style scoped>
a {background-color: #f9fda2;} /* highlight */
/* without inherit h1 won’t get the link’s background-color */
a h1 {background-color: inherit;}
</style>
  <a href="/">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>meta</p>
  </a>
</header>
```